# Multiple Formula in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

There were similar question on this thread but none answers the question I've have. Hope someone could help.

I've two formulas, one formula helps to calculate the time difference by excluding the weekends and other formula helps to calculate the time difference without excluding anything.

Formula 1: `=NETWORKDAYS(W2,X2)-1-MOD(W2,1)+MOD(X2,1)`

Formula 2: `=TEXT(X10-W10, "[h]:mm:ss")`

In column "W", I've Opened Date in following format "11/24/2020 1:14 AM" , In column "X" I've closed date in same format.

In column "Z" I've the formula picker, the formula picking conditions are:
If value in column "Z" is:
CAT1 apply formula 2
CAT2 apply formula 2
CAT3 apply formula 1
CAT4 apply formula 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an IF for this:

```
=IF( OR (Z1 = "CAT1" , Z1 = "CAT2") , put formula 2 here , put formula 1 here )
```

For the full working formula:

```
=IF( OR (Z1 = "CAT1" , Z1 = "CAT2") , TEXT(X10-W10, "[h]:mm:ss") , NETWORKDAYS(W2,X2)-1-MOD(W2,1)+MOD(X2,1) )
```

For error trapping as per comment use:

```
=IFERROR(IF( OR (Z1 = "CAT1" , Z1 = "CAT2") , TEXT(X10-W10, "[h]:mm:ss") , NETWORKDAYS(W2,X2)-1-MOD(W2,1)+MOD(X2,1) ),TEXT(X10-W10, "[h]:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: Thanks, will check and come back. Appreciate it.

Comment: Works just like I wanted! Thank You Very Much Pete!

Comment: Is it possible to add a ERROR condition?

Comment: accidently posted the comment before completing the question: Is it possible to add a ERROR condition? If create date or resolve date falls in weekend, my formula 1 throws error, #### error. What I'm looking for is, when it throws error (#### error), I want to use formula 1   TEXT(X10-W10, "[h]:mm:ss")

Comment: @Felix yeah sure see updated answer

Comment: The formula that is supposed to be triggered when I get ##### value isn't working. I'm still getting #####. Scenario: Create date: 11/28/2020  9:22:24 PM Resolve Date: 11/30/2020  9:14:25 AM ; As per my formula picker condition it should apply formula 2 (NETWORKDAYS), And yes it did apply formula 2. The reason I'm getting ##### in result is because created day is weekend (Sat). When created or resolved date falls in weekends my NETWORKDAYS formula throws this error.

Comment: Here is the formula I used:

Comment: Here is the formula I used: =IFERROR(IF(OR(CA2="CAT-1",CA2="CAT-3",CA2="CAT-6"),TEXT(X2-W2, "[h]:mm:ss"),NETWORKDAYS(W2,X2)-1-MOD(W2,1)+MOD(X2,1)),TEXT(X2-W2, "[h]:mm:ss"))

Column CA is formula condition picker
Column W is Create Date
Column X is Resolved Date